# MS SQL datetime: hh:mm:ss is removed when persisted through Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to perform a Cron operation copying some data from one database to another, using Entity Framework Core. The data I'm copying has a DateTime and I'm trying to use this to make sure only new data is persisted, but when I persist to the new database the hh:mm:ss is removed and I'll end up with a date like: 17-08-2016 00:00:00.
This is a problem as the data I compare to will have a later datetime and therefore be dublicated.

```
List<ServiceModels.TblUserTransactions> transactions = getNewUserTransactions();
transactions = transactions.OrderBy(t => t.Date).ToList();
foreach (ServiceModels.TblUserTransactions transaction in transactions)
            {
                context.TblUserTransactions.Add(transaction);
            }
context.SaveChanges();
```

I have checked that the DateTime Object is correct before persisiting by having a Console.Writeline(transactions.Last().Date); check.

Comment: Just to make sure, the new database columns are identical right? You're not using Date instead of DateTime?

Comment: yes they are identical it will end up as dd-MM-hh 00:00:00 in the new database

Comment: If you add the following line (above your SaveChanges), you can view your query in the output window. Does it look the way you expect it to? context.Database.Log = s => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); };

Comment: Entity Framework Core doesn't have a logger build in so I'll have to implement it first. I'll properly not have time to do that today but I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well some magic happened during the night and it seems the code is actually working as intending. I'm getting the hh:mm:ss now aswell without having changed anything